# Issue with creating Video files from Binary files

Tags: video, ffmpeg, binaryfiles, moviepy, web-mediarecorder

We have a bunch of binary files that represent Video data.
This is how the binary files were created:

1. Used MediaRecorder from a React application to capture the browser window.
   To capture the screen stream we used (Navigator.)MediaDevices.getDisplayMedia() API
2. Each video is recorded for 1-second duration
3. This data is then encoded with base64 and sent through a websocket. The server decodes the base64 string and stores the binary data in a file (without any extension)

So we now have a bunch of binary files each containing 1 second worth of video data.

The issue is, we are not able to convert all the binary files back to a single video.

1. We tried using ffmpeg

   copy /b * merged.

   ffmpeg -i merged merged.mp4

Basically first merging all the binary files and converting to mp4. It didn't work. The resulting video duration is not equal to the (number_of_files) in seconds.

2. We also tried converting individual chunks with ffmpeg but we get the below error:

   [h264 @ 000001522dc74b80] [error] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
   [h264 @ 000001522dc74b80] [error] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
   [h264 @ 000001522dc74b80] [error] decode_slice_header error
   [h264 @ 000001522dc74b80] [error] no frame!
   I can provide the complete logs if needed.
3. Next thing we tried was to use MoviePy library in Python. We programmatically concatenated the files and saved them as WebM and imported it into MoviePy as a Video.

In all the above approaches, we couldn't get the full video.

Comment: You have to define the frame size, pixel format and select `rawvideo` format. Example: `ffmpeg -r 10 -f rawvideo -video_size 1920x1080 -pixel_format bgr24 merged merged.mp4`. Do you know the resolution and the pixel format of your recorded video? Is it a pure binary file without any headers? Can you share a short sample "merged" binary file?

Comment: @Rotem tanks for your inputs. When I try to run the above command, I am getting this error:
[rawvideo @ 000002db70be9200] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 21).ate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A
dy2: corrupt input packet in stream 0

[rawvideo @ 000002db70bf2ec0] Invalid buffer size, packet size 233403 < expected frame_size 3147264

Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument

The recorded resolution is 1366x768. Some files have headers and some files don't have headers.

Comment: The error applies only the last frame. I forgot the `-i`: `ffmpeg -r 10 -f rawvideo -video_size 1366x768 -pixel_format bgr24 -i merged merged.mp4`

Comment: I asked you about the pixel format, is it `bgr24`? The chances are low.

Comment: With headers, the above command is not going to work. Without headers, make sure the file size is in bytes is a multiple of `1366*768`.

Comment: @Rotem 
After exploring further, this is the error we are getting now:






[rawvideo @ 0000026617e99100] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 442).918.3kbits/s speed=3.07x
dy2: corrupt input packet in stream 0
[rawvideo @ 0000026617ec7780] Invalid buffer size, packet size 25947 < expected frame_size 150000
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument
frame=  442 fps= 78 q=-1.0 Lsize=   19453kB time=00:00:17.56 bitrate=9074.9kbits/s speed=3.08x
video:19450kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.013702%

Comment: I don't think I am able to help you with that.